# c# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The connection is already open.'

Tags: c#

I'm coding a Windows Forms login page for an administration application. My problem is, that when I try to log on, I get the error message

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The connection is already open.'

Any help would be appreciated

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection (@"Database= app2000; Data Source = localhost; User = root; Password =''");
    int i;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i = 0;
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM adminlogin WHERE username='" + txtBoxUsername + "'AND password='" + txtBoxPassword + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

        if (i == 0)
        {
            lblerrorInput.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Hide();
            Main ss = new Main();
            ss.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to close the connection after all operation in finally section or using section.

Comment: Do you get that exception the **first** you click the button? The **second** time you get it for sure, because, well, you already opened the connection. Call `con.Close()` at the end of the button handler or - better - enclose the declaration and usage of `con` in a `using` statement.

Comment: The SDF file is already being used by another application Or already opened in your application).  Windows is not designed to share files.  You could make the file shared but you may loose data.

Comment: Use `using` blocks where possible, which will automatically take care of closing the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not *cache* Connection, it's a typical antipattern, but recreate it when you need it

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form {
   ...
   //DONE: Extract method
   private static bool UserExists(string userName, string password) {
     //DONE: Do not cache connections, but recreate them
     using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection (@"...") {
        con.Open();

        //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

          //DONE: Make query being readable
          //DONE: Make query being parametrized
          cmd.CommandText = 
            @"SELECT * 
                FROM adminlogin 
               WHERE username = @UserName 
                 AND password = @PassWord"; // <- A-A-A! Password as a plain text!

          //TODO: the simplest, but not the best solution: 
          // better to create parameters explicitly
          // cmd.Parameters.Add(...)
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtBoxUsername);   
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassWord", txtBoxPassword);   

          // If we have at least one record, the user exists
          using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            return (reader.Read()); 
          }
        }
     }   
   }
```

Finally

```
   private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (!UserExists(txtBoxUsername.Text, txtBoxPassword.Text))  
       lblerrorInput.Show();
     else {
       Hide();
       Main ss = new Main();
       ss.Show();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Nice answer, I especially like the little `AAA!` ^^

Comment: Oh, btw: `txtBoxUsername` should probably be `userName` (same for password)

Comment: Does AAA stand for something particular or is it just a string that can be searched for in your code?

Comment: I think it's a scream (Aaaaah, what are you doing!?)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the connection, use `con.Close()` at the end to close the connection and avoid this error the next time the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code.

- You should close the sql connection when you finished your process.
- I suggest you to use `using` statement to dispose connection instance after complete database actions.
- Also, you should use command parameters to prevent Sql injection.

You can declare connection string like this;

```
private string _connectionString = @"Database= app2000; Data Source = localhost; User = root; Password =''";
```

The method part looks like;

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    i = 0;
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM adminlogin WHERE username = @username and password = @password";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtBoxUsername);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtBoxPassword);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

    if (i == 0)
    {
        lblerrorInput.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Hide();
        Main ss = new Main();
        ss.Show();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please don't promote SQL-Injection. I'll remove my Downvote once that's fixed, but as it is now, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: You might also want to separate the first bit of your code block (the connections string) from the second (the rest) since it currently looks like invalid code due to the fact you have a field declaration and then at the same scope a bunch of code that in reality should be inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't cache your `Connection` objects.  It's a terrible practice and I've had to go back and fix it every time I accept a new job and inherit code.  Most database access classes implement `IDisposable`, so use `using` and take advantage of it to keep your code clean. FYI, `Readers` and `Adapters` are also `IDisposable` so you can do the same with them, too.

```
string command = "select stuff from mydata";
string connection = GetConnectionStringFromEncryptedConfigFile();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn))
       {
          cmd.Connection.Open();
          //do stuff            
       }
    }
```

Second, if you're *forced* to use a cached connection (i.e., you inherited horrible code and don't have time to fix it yet), check your `State` first.

```
if(conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
   conn.Open();
}
```

Note that there are a lot more states than just `Open` and `Closed`, and if you try to open a connection that is busy, you'll still get errors.  It's still a much wiser approach to use the `IDisposable` implementations with `using` so you don't have to worry about this sort of thing so much.